# Angular 7 Extract data from observable

Tags: javascript, json

I am new in angular.

i want extract data from an observable. i do that :

```
validnomi(key : string): void {
  this.demandesnomiftodisplay = 
    this.demandenomisService.getSingleDemandenomis(key).subscribe(val => 

    {const civ = val[0].civ; 
     const datedemande = val[0].datedemande; 
     const nom = val[0].nom; 
     const prenom = val[0].prenom; 

     }
  );
}
```

my service.ts :

```
getSingleDemandenomis(key: string){
return this.database.list('/Demandes/DemandesBALnominatives', ref => ref.orderByKey().equalTo(key)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.val();
    const key = a.payload.key;
    return {key, ...data };
  });
}));
 }
```

But i have this error :

```
property prenom does not exist on type {key : string}
property nom does not exist on type {key : string}
property civdoes not exist on type {key : string}
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets from your log indicates that you are not getting an object but rather an array of object. Just get the first element of the array and then you will be able to access all the attributes of your object.

Also, you should not use `JSON.stringify()`, as it turns your array of object into a string.

```
validnomi(key : string) {
    this.demandesnomiftodisplay = this.demandenomisService.getSingleDemandenomis(key).subscribe(val => 
        // This will get the key from your object
        console.log(val[0].key);
    );
}
```

Comment: i have this error : property subscribe does not exist on type operatorfunction

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct, you just need further to read first element of array and access needed property.

Your service:

```
getSingleDemandenomis(key: string): Observable<{key: string; datedemande: string}[]> {
   return this.database.list('/Demandes/DemandesBALnominatives', ref => 
       ref.orderByKey().equalTo(key)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.val();
              const payloadKey = a.payload.key;
              return {key: payloadKey, ...data };
          });
   }));
 }
```

Component:

```
validnomi(key : string) {
    this.demandesnomiftodisplay = this.demandenomisService.getSingleDemandenomis(key)
    .subscribe((val: {datedemande: string}[]) => console.log(val[0].datedemande));
}
```

Comment: i have this error : property 'datedemande" does not exist on type {key : string}

Comment: @AlanENTEM it looks like you have some wrong types defined. Please check my edited answer for hint.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your `getSingleDemandenomis` method too? So I can help you with correct types.

Comment: I added some a return type for your service, and fixed shallow name issue. Try that. Please consider checking more into TypeScript, to get better familiar with types.

Comment: i have  type {key : string;}[] is not asssignable to type {key:string, datedemande:string} idon't understand this problem so i can use my fonction correctly but it send me this error

Comment: Okay, in order to help resolve your problem, it would be better if you could provide minimal reproducible app state in an online editor like https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to the observable:

```
validnomi(key : string) {
  this.demandesnomiftodisplay = 
    this.demandenomisService.getSingleDemandenomis(key).pipe(
    pluck('datademande')
  ).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pqcet) to illustrate.

Comment: That should be the way to go IMHO. I removed my answer as `pluck` seems to be a better match for the case. Get my upvote